# How to segment audio file and play each segment in loop

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I want to segment an audio file by 5 seconds (each segment) i want to send that each segment to google speech API to recognize the text of audio and also want to perform some other operation during it.

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(26)

sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound1.ogg")
sound2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound2.ogg")

sound1.play(loops = -1)
time.sleep (2)

sound2.play(loop = -1)
```